# How to implement comparison between two diffrent types?

Tags: rust

First "type" is an enum

```
pub enum Symbol {
    X,
    O,
}
```

Second is a also an enum

```
pub enum CellContent {
    Move(Symbol),
    None,
}
```

Having these 3 only variants allowed

```
let cellX = CellContent::Move(Symbol::X);
let cellO = CellContent::Move(Symbol::O);
let cellEmpty = CellContent::None;
```

How can I compare a CellContent with a Symbol ?

```
assert_eq(cellX, Symbol::X);
assert_eq(cellY, Symbol::X);
```

I tried

```
impl PartialEq<Symbol> for CellContent {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Symbol) -> bool {
        if self == CellContent::None {
            return false;
        }
        true;
    }
}
```

the first comparison doesn't compile because can't compare `&structs::CellContent` with `structs::CellContent`

and obviously i cannot return true in the other case but I must compare if self is a Move(Symbol::X)  and other is a Symbol::X, or CellConent is a Move(Symbol::)  and other is a Symbol::X

I have no idea of how to write these 3 comparison

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should derive `Eq` and `PartialEq` for your enums first, so that they can be compared to themselves. After that, you can check if a move is equal to a symbol, or always return false if there is no move:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq)]
pub enum Symbol {
    X,
    O,
}

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq)]
pub enum CellContent {
    Move(Symbol),
    None,
}

impl PartialEq<Symbol> for CellContent {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Symbol) -> bool {
        match self {
            CellContent::Move(symbol) => symbol == other,
            CellContent::None => false,
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let cellX = CellContent::Move(Symbol::X);
    let cellO = CellContent::Move(Symbol::O);
    let cellEmpty = CellContent::None;

    assert_eq!(cellX, CellContent::None);
}
```

(I also derived `Debug` to see prettier error messages)

Comment: Can you explain me why "You should derive Eq and PartialEq for your enums first, so that they can be compared to themselve" ?

Comment: You probably want any `Symbol::X` to equal any other `Symbol::X`, and while you could write that yourself, a `#[derive(PartialEq, Eq)]` will automatically do all that for you. Otherwise, there is no way to get a result for `Symbol == Symbol`. After that exists, you can use the `PartialEq` trait to also say that a `Move(Symbol::X)` is equal to a `Symbol::X`, like in the example (at the `symbol == other` line).

Comment: Just to try, I didn't derive EQ at it works anyway

Comment: In this case, yeah. `PartialEq` is what actually overloads the `==` operator, but a lot of times it doesn't make sense to not also `impl Eq`.

Comment: i will ask a separate question for PartialEq an Eq